# Modify store request in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs4

I had some issues with the structure of requests, which the tree-store sent. But I could modify it with an beforeload listener.

```
store.on( 'beforeload', function( s, o ) {
  if( o.params.parent === 'root' ) delete o.params.parent; 
});
```

In the normal store, the operation argument doesn't contain a params attribute somehow...
Problem is, the server always want a `sortby` and `sortorder` parameter, but

the store has

- just a sort parameter (which contains the sortby and sortorder)
- just sends this parameter when I sort a table and not at begining (if I put it in extra params of the proxy, this always overrides the store sort parameter)

So I want to split `sort` up into `sortby` and `sortorder` and send those params every time the store requests something.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I got by with 3 config parameters for the proxy:

```
simpleSortMode: true
sortParam     : 'sortby'
directionParam: 'sortorder'
```

which split the

```
.../?sort=[[{property:'visits', direction: 'DESC'}]]&...
```

into

```
.../?sortby=visits&sortorder=DESC&...
```

The second problem, that the store didn't send the sort parameters from the beginning I solved with the `sort()` method of the store.

```
...
constructor: function( config ) {
   this.callParent([config]);
   this.sort( config.sortby, config.sortorder );
}
...
```

I simply used it to init the store with default sorting, before it even loaded data from the server. This caused it to send the sort-params with the first request.